# how to find out which chain in iptables in listing

Tags: iptables, firewall

Suppose I have the following two entries line of iptables:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j DROP
```

So, I have `POSTROUTING` and `INPUT` chains.
Then I can get the result list with:

```
iptables -L  -t nat -n --line-numbers -t filter
```

My result is:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:70
2    DROP       all  --  10.10.10.0/24        0.0.0.0/0
```

**My quesion is**, how can I find out which rule belongs to `POSTROUTING` and which belongs to `INPUT` ?

Answer (score 2):

with this command: `iptables -L  -t nat -n --line-numbers -t filter` , you can see ***only*** `filter` table rules!

you must separate run :

```
iptables -L  -t nat -n --line-numbers
```

for see `nat` table rules and

```
iptables -L  -n --line-numbers
```

for see `filter` table rules

Comment: See also `iptables-save` to see everything at once

Comment: It's not my answer, i need to find out chain of each rule.